# Replacing NA values with 0 in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I'm trying to replace my NA values in a data.frame to 0's.
I know this is a very simple question, but for some reason it is not working for me. This is my code so far:

```
library(XLConnect)
filenames <- list.files( paste(mainDir,sep=""), pattern="Output.*xls", full.names=TRUE)

data = lapply(filenames, function(f) {
wb = loadWorkbook(f)
readWorksheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb), startRow = 1, startCol = 1, header=TRUE) })

for (i in 1:length(data)){
data[[i]][is.na(data[[i]])] <- 0}
```

My `data` contains 6 data frames, each which look something like this:

```
    X    North    South    East    West
1   1      1.4      -0.8     NA     0.2
2   2      0.8       0.1     NA      NA
3   3      1.1       NA      0.3     NA
4   4      0.7       -0.3    0.5     NA    
:   :        :          :      :      :
:   :        :          :      :      :
```

Even if I try replacing the NA's in individual data frames like this:

```
x<-data[[1]]
x[is.na(x)]<-0
```

it does not work either, but no errors come up. I have checked `str(data)` and my data is definitely in a `data.frame`

EDIT: output of `dput(head(data))`, the data is quite large so these are just the first few lines, and end few lines, but it's all very similar

```
list(structure(list(X.......... = c("01", "02", "03", 
"04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", 
"10", "11", "12"), North = c("NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "159268.712943834", "159268.712943834", 
"159268.712943834", "NA", "NA"), South = c(0.606714762968571, 
0.814522728179517, 0.209726636027901, 0.0444084477658611, -0.374746980093072, 
-0.686918667591031, -0.00947578135844365, -0.579281055756145, 
-0.447180610635141, 0.0364485438280426, 0.293432135759165, -0.128575801748206
), East = c(0.0453524581429493, -0.715043414690337, -0.726352946071858, 
-0.211008344503713, 0.159243426048929, 0.124256257795459, -0.971001351195061, 
-1.11413010910649, -0.608926167442848, -1.29473850887024, -1.2685456908235, 
-2.19150672218728)
:
:
:
:
.Names = c("X..........", "North", "South", "East", "West"......
:
:
row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(m = c(0, 0)), .Names = "m", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L), class = "data.frame"))
```

output for `str(data)`, again there is a lot of data but it is all very similar so here are the first few lines:

```
List of 6
 $ :'data.frame':       12 obs. of  24 variables:
  ..$ X..........: chr [1:12] "01" "02" "03" "04" ...
  ..$ North   : chr [1:12] "NA" "NA" "NA" "NA" ...
  ..$ South  : num [1:12] 0.6067 0.8145 0.2097 0.0444 -0.3747 ...
  ..$ East      : num [1:12] 0.0454 -0.715 -0.7264 -0.211 0.1592 ...
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `dput(head(data))` and `str(data)`?

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` in `for (i in length(data){`.

Comment: And a `for( i in 1:length(data) ){...}`.

Comment: oops yes I did miss the closing ) and 1:length(data) but that's just because I quickly typed it in here, it is in the orginal code and it still doesn't work

Comment: @joran I have added outputs for `dput(head(data))` and `str(data)`

Comment: You have a problem in your data. Some of you NA columns are coded as characters. "NA" is not recognized by the is.na function. is.na(c(2,3,5,"NA")) gives FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE meanwhile is.na(c(2,3,5,NA)) gives FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE.

Comment: @Dr.Mike is correct here.  Your "NA" entries are strings rather than `NA` values, so the 'is.na' function is not working properly.  Try `data[[i]][data[[i]]=="NA"] <- 0` and see if that helps.

Comment: Looks like NA is really the character "NA", so `x[x == "NA"] <- 0' should work.

Comment: @Dr.Mike Please write up and submit your answer, so we can close this out properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your data. Some of you NA columns are coded as characters. "NA" is not recognized by the is.na function. See the following example:

```
is.na(c(2,3,5,"NA"))
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

meanwhile the following code does what you want.

```
is.na(c(2,3,5,NA)) 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Just replace the "NA" with NA and your code should work fine.